# Proof that outer measure splits over an open interval.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu^*(A)$ denote the outer measure of $A$, which is defined in the usual sense of taking the infimum of the lengths of coverings by open intervals.

I am trying to show that for $A\subseteq \mathbf{R}$ and $x>0$, then $\mu^*(A)=\mu^*(A\cap (-x,x))+\mu^*(A\cap(\mathbf{R}\setminus (-x,x)))$.

To show this, I know that the union of every pair of interval coverings for $A\cap (-x,x)$ and $A\cap(\mathbf{R}\setminus (-x,x))$ gives a covering for $A$; I can then take the infimum and prove that $\mu^*(A)\leq \mu^*(A\cap (-x,x))+\mu^*(A\cap(\mathbf{R}\setminus (-x,x)))$.

For the other inequality, I am not so sure. It seems like I could take a covering for $A$, give myself an $\varepsilon$ of room, and split the intervals covering $A$ into two intervals, one for $A\cap (-t,t)$ and another for $A\cap (\mathbf{R}\setminus (-t,t))$. But this seems kind of ugly.

Is there a better way to do this?